# Count of duplicate items in a C# list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, counting

I wanted to know how to count all the duplicate strings in a list in  C# in winform Application.

```
List<string> colorList = new List<string> { "red", "red", "yellow", "blue", "blue", "orange", "green", "red" };
```

For example I have the above list and the count would be 5, because "red" appears 3 times and "blue" appears twice.

Happy to use loops or LINQ or anything necessary.

In my actual program this list can be quite larger with 1000s of entries so performance is something to consider also.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: I dont need to know which one occurs the most or anything like that, strictly just increment the count whenever a duplicate value is found

Comment: Note that it is better to edit your question instead of posting this as comment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you just need the total count:

```
var total = colorList.GroupBy(_ => _).Where(_ => _.Count() > 1).Sum(_ => _.Count());
```

An alternative which might be faster with large data sets:

```
var hashset = new HashSet<string>(); // to determine if we already have seen this color
var duplicates = new HashSet<string>(); // will contain the colors that are duplicates
var count = 0;
foreach (var color in colorList)
{
    if (!hashset.Add(color))
    {
        count++;
        if (duplicates.Add(color))
            count++;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: measured both methods with a list of 2^25 (approx. 30 million) entries: first one 3.7 seconds, second one 3.2 seconds.

Comment: Liked the way u used discards.

Comment: Thanks very much! Appreciate the advice, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

If you just need the count of the duplicate items:

```
 List<string> colorList = new List<string> { "red", "red", "yellow", "blue", "blue", "orange", "green", "red" };

 var count = colorList.GroupBy(item => item)
                      .Where(item => item.Count() > 1)
                      .Sum(item => item.Count());
```

Try this for item by item details:

```
var result = colorList.GroupBy(item => item)
                      .Select(item => new
                          {
                              Name = item.Key,
                              Count = item.Count()
                          })
                      .OrderByDescending(item => item.Count)
                      .ThenBy(item => item.Name)
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing the count of the duplicates items in a C# can be as follow:-

```
 var duplicates = from d in list
 group d by d into c
 let count = c.Count()
 orderby count descending
 select new { Value = c.Key, Count = count };

  foreach (var v in duplicates)
  {
     string strValue = v.Value;
     int Count = v.Count;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I would do it without group by

```
List<string> colorList = new List<string> { "red", "red", "yellow", "blue", "blue", "orange", "green", "red" };
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var item in colorList.Distinct().ToList())
        {
            var cnt = colorList.Count(i => i.Equals(item, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (cnt > 1)
                count += cnt;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as fast as the accepted answer, but for the reference one can also use a dictionary to count the hits:

```cs
var map = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var color in colorList))
{
    if (map.ContainsKey(color)) map[color]++;
    else map.Add(color, 1);
}

return map.Values.Count(x => x > 1);
```

It's much faster than a LINQ `GroupBy`